# Need help to adjust css for div class

Tags: css, html

I pasted this code into my header.php file to get an opt-in button:

```
<div class="createsend-button" style="height:27px;display:inline-block;"data-listid="r/72/191/0E3/389738A3FFEDFFA8">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">....</script>
```

I can't seem to control the placement - if I add .createsend-button to css there's no effect. When I look at this in Firebug it says this div class is actually .subscribe-button-inner but customizing that class in css has no effect either.

What am I missing here?

My site is at : http://tinyurl.com/c5eujcj

Comment: Please don't use short links.

Comment: show the css as well.

Comment: there should be an space between " and data

Comment: sorry for the short link but this is for a client and I don't want it to show up in searches.

Comment: Using the short link won't affect crawlers.

Comment: I was trying to add this to my css without any effect:

`.subscribe-button-inner {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 120px;}`

Comment: win-safari.css doesn't exist on server

Comment: The problem is in what createsend inserts. See my answer.

Comment: What script `<script>` are you including? It may be overwriting your styles, in which case you may need to move it above your `div` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe for the createsend button has inline CSS including `position: absolute`. If createsend offers an option to change the button, that would be your best option. If not, use this:

```
<div class="applyStylesToThis">
   <div class="createsend-button" style="height:27px;display:inline-block;" data-listid="r/72/191/0E3/389738A3FFEDFFA8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I didn't realize I'd have to enclose the div in a separate div.

Comment: Good! Please mark my answer as 'best answer' for future users.